# Are atomic operations always preformed sequentially within the same CPU cycle?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, cpu-architecture

If I have some simple non-atomic code like so:

```
a++;
```

which can be broken down to machine instructions like so:

```
MOV EAX, [a]
INC EAX
MOV [a], EAX
```

I'm not familiar with machine code, please excuse me if that is incorrect, but basically assume that they are preformed atomically

Am I right in thinking that the CPU could preform the first action, then run numerous cycles, then do the next action, more cycles, then finally the last part of the machine code?

As apposed to preforming each bit of machine code sequentially to each other with-in the same cycle.

Comment: It's indeed correct. However, you should generally not have to worry about this fact, except if you are very concerned with performance...

Comment: The word is "perform".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On modern x86/x64 processors you can't even assume that a single architectural instruction maps to a single CPU (machine) instruction. Modern CPUs generally implement x86/x64 instructions internally as a series of architecture specific microcode instructions. The order these are executed in doesn't map in any simple way to the order they appear in in your executable due to out of order execution, speculative execution, etc. There is also no simple mapping between CPU clock cycles and number of instructions executed.

On top of this, with multithreaded code your thread may be context switched at any time so there can be arbitrarily long delays with arbitrary other operations occurring between any two instructions being executed.

The only way to get logical atomicity in a modern multithreaded envrionment is to use the appropriate atomic and synchronization instructions provided by the architecture which guarantee atomic behavior not just at the instruction level but across the memory hierarchy (L1, L2, L3 cache and main memory, plus store buffers etc.).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I understand synchronization and atomicity techniques are provided in modern environments. But what I mean to ask, it is possible in-between machine instructions that the CPU will perform an action elsewhere in the operating system? Which explains why it is impossible for two threads to check a lock at the exact same time.

Comment: Yes, even with a single CPU you can context switch at any time to another thread between any two instructions. With multiple cores as found on most modern systems you can have two CPUs attempting to access the same address simultaneously as well.

Answer (score 2):

Most CPUs found in computers since the Pentium have indeed used out of order execution. This is a very complex process by which high level instructions are first decomposed into very small operations, then put into an execution queue where instructions are executed in the order in which input operands become available. You might read a more detailed description on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution).